# Question about により

Tags: grammar

Full text:

> 本車両には、車両の制御や操作に関するデータなどを記録するコン ピューターが装備されており、各機能の作動時や操作状況[により]{LLL}、主に 次のようなデータを記録します。

I want to understand what により here implies.

My understanding: The vehicle data is recorded by computer for control and operations of the vehicle and for each operation function time and operation status data is primarily recorded.

My Issue: により meaning is "by means of". So, does the primary vehicle operation function time and operation status is primarily recorded and the control and operations are recorded as a result, or is it vice-versa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ～により means "depending on~~".

Some examples:
「状況により」「状況によって(は)」"depending on the circumstance"
「場合により」「場合によって(は)」"depending on the situation"
「時と場合により」「時と場合によって(は)」"depending on the time and situation"
「文脈により」「文脈によって(は)」"depending on the context"

Related threads:

- [による for highlighting differences](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/36651/9831)
- [What's the difference between による, により and によって?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3649/9831)
- [Why 次第 instead of によって in this very example?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/30918/9831)